# HTTP error code 301

Tags: arduino, server, webclient, http-get, ethernet

I am using the web client demo to send an HTTP GET request to a web server to read the data in json format. However the web server returns an error code 301 page moved error. How do I redirect my request to the new location?

Comment: Add more juice to your question...which type of server? server configuration? is it hosted? some code?,etc etc

Comment: How do I go about redirecting the GET request? This is the sample piece of code I am using to send without redirects.

`code`
if(client2.connect(server2, 80))
  {
    Serial.println("connection success goog");
    // send the HTTP PUT request:
    client2.println("GET /feeds/cells/SPID/5/public/basic?range=D10 HTTP/1.1");
    client2.println("Host: spreadsheets.google.com");
    client2.println("Connection: close");
    client2.println();
  }
`code`

Comment: @davide andreazzini